# Is it able to place the blue dot to my specify location in MapKit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to display the blue dot to specify location but it's always show the current location. Is there any way to move the blue dot to another location ? 
If not, is there any way to make a dot sam as blue dot, and that dot cannot to drag or move. Please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No. The blue dot is intended to display the user's current location.  That is all Apple's frameworks let you do.

You could probably create a custom animation that would simulate the look of the blue dot somewhere else on the map, but I would expect Apple to reject any app that did that since it is their intention that the blue dot ALWAYS show the user's current location, and doing anything else with that symbol would cause user confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to create a blue dot and to place it anywhere you want on the map.

However Apple use a blue dot to indicate the current user's location so I don't know what will happen when you submit to the app store if your dot represents something else other than the user's location.

But you could create a dot that is not blue and do whatever you want with that. You would need to derive a class from MKAnnotationView and set it to draw a dot and whatever color you want and then add it to the map.

The code to do that is too long to post, but its easy to find tutorials and ready-made code that does this using google.